# How to remove allocated bootstrap keywords

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has allocated many keywords that we use when we develop web projects. Such as: container, navbar, nav, etc.. Sometimes I use these keywords for some of my projects. But for some other projects I don't need any feature of these keywords but I need the names. Is there any way to disable these keywords without overwriting them?

These keywords are important because these are what we call good practice. I don't like using menu or navigation-bar instead of navbar. So, is there any way to disable css of these keywords?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the downfalls of using a framework, and you have to ask yourself at one point whether it's worth your time building your own boilerplate for projects.

As for your question, I don't believe there's a "safe" way to do that with the vanilla css file, but if you have ruby installed and you download the [SASS version](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) you may be able to remove some of the other stuff you don't need by selectively commenting out components in _bootstrap.scss:

```
 @import "bootstrap/component-animations";
 @import "bootstrap/dropdowns";
 @import "bootstrap/button-groups";
 @import "bootstrap/input-groups";
// @import "bootstrap/navs";
 @import "bootstrap/navbar";
 @import "bootstrap/breadcrumbs";
 @import "bootstrap/pagination";
 @import "bootstrap/pager";
```

Comment: I am developing ruby on rails applications with the sass version of bootstrap, but never heard such a thing.

Comment: @cyonder in _bootstrap.scss you have a partials list full of `@import "bootstrap/component-animations";` You may be able to cull some of the stuff you dont need by removing some of these, like `@import "bootstrap/navbar";` for example.